# C++ std::string usage with !=, <, and >

Tags: c++, string

What are the examples on usages of `std::string` class with `!=`, `>`, and `<`?

Comment: is this a homework assignment? Do you mean std::string, or char-based strings?

Comment: C++ string = std::string, C string = char*

Comment: This strikes me as a very senseless question. What about these three operators is not clear to you? Have you done any experiments, read any documentation or done any googling?

Comment: Did you ever try to Google? You can find dozens of examples.

Comment: @Jeff Paquette. This is not a homework assignment, and just following as self-study a lab material of a university. I mean here `std::string`. Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- `s1 != s2` returns true if s1 is not equal to s2. It's case sensitive!
- `s1 < s2` returns true if s1 comes before s2 if they're arranged in dictionary order. If `string s1 ="Nawaz"` and `string s2 = "nawaz"`, then `s1 < s2` will return `true`.
- `s1 > s2` returns true if s1 comes after s2 if they're arranged in dictionary order.

As a general guideline, ascii value of uppercases is smaller than the ascii value of lowercases: `A` is smaller than `a`, `B` is smaller than `b`, and so on.

So uppercases are considered *before* the lowercases. By dictionary order, I meant the same thing. `"A"` is before `"a"`. `"Nawaz"` is before `"nawaz"`, `"nAwaz"`, `"nAWAZ"` etc.

Compare character by character:

- If ascii value of all characters in one string is equal to the ascii value of *corresponding* characters in the other string, then the two strings are  equal.
- If ascii value of a character is smaller than the corresponding character in the other string, then the  first string is considered smaller. No need to compare all characters.
- If so far all characters are equal, and you reached to the end in the first string, while there are still some characters in the second string to be compared, then the first string is considered smaller. That means, `"Nawa"` is smaller than `"Nawaz"`

I hope this explanation helps you understanding how comparisons work for `std::string`.

Comment: @user588855 This is the answer you are looking for! (*waves hands hypnotically*)